# Capitalizing words in a CSV file

Tags: python, csv, capitalize

i want to change data from csv files to update in my database:

Their are like that:

```
01;NAME SECONDNAME LASTNAME;STREET ADDRESS;548
02;NAME SECONDNAME LASTNAME;STREET ADDRESS;421
```

I want to make it:

```
01;Name Secondname Lastname;Street Address;548
02;Name Secondname Lastname;Street Address;421
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`str.title()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=title#str.title):

```
with open('text.txt','r') as f:
    t = f.read().title()
with open('text.txt','w') as f:
    f.write(t)
```